# Is there a simple way to mention all of a Discord user's roles?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I had a go at using a Collection and a `for...of` loop to push a user's role cache into the aforementioned Collection, but is there a simpler way? I'm just wondering.

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Could you please direct me to another site where I can ask a question and get a direct answer? You've shown me this site is more for fixing bugs than asking for information.

Comment: Do you want a way to push a user's role cache into a collection, or a way to mention all of their roles?

Comment: That's not exactly true. We just need and expect more information on which to base answers. Please show us your attempt and be very clear about how it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will display all server roles, If the text exceeds 2000 characters it will be sent in 2 messages

```js
c.on("message", message => {
   if((message.content.startsWith("serverroles")) {
       let rolemap = message.guild.roles.cache.map(r => '`'+r.name+'`').join(' ')

            if (!rolemap) rolemap = "There is no roles";    
      for(let i = 0; i < rolemap.length; i += 2000) {
    const toSend = rolemap.substring(i, Math.min(rolemap.length, i + 2000));
          message.channel.send(tosend)
}}});
```

Comment: Thanks! Just a few tweaks and the code did exactly what I wanted.

Comment: Instead of creating a `for` loop, you can just use the built in `split` option. `message.channel.send(rolemap, { split: true })`